# Gradle doesn't copy html files into executed jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
        springRestDocsVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
        gradleDockerVersion   = '1.2'
        asciidoctorGradlePluginVersion   = '1.5.9.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:${asciidoctorGradlePluginVersion}")
        classpath("se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:${gradleDockerVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.6.RELEASE"
  id "org.asciidoctor.convert" version "1.5.9.2"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.asciidoctor.convert'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'docker'

apply from: 'local.gradle'

mainClassName = 'class.path.package.BootApplication'

version = '0.0.3a'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Standard spring boot packages
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client')

    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    compile('biz.paluch.redis:lettuce:4.4.6.Final')
    compile('org.pacesys:openstack4j-core:3.1.0')
    compile('org.pacesys.openstack4j.connectors:openstack4j-httpclient:3.1.0')

    // Dozer object mapping
    compile('net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.5.1')
    // Sengrid library
    compile('com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.2.1')
    compile('org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.28')
    // Cloudant
    compile('com.cloudant:cloudant-client:2.9.0')
    compile('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.2')
    compile('org.json:json:20171018')
    compile('javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final')
    //Swagger2
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2')

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile("org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc")
    testCompile("org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.2")

    asciidoctor('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor:2.0.2.RELEASE')

}

processResources {
//    expand(project.properties)
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RELEASE'
    snippetsDir = file('build/generated-snippets')
//  springRestDocsVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
}

ext['spring-restdocs.version'] = '${springRestDocsVersion}'

test { 
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

asciidoctor {
//    attributes "snippets": snippetsDir
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}

jar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor 
    from ('${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5') { 
        into 'static/apidocs'
    }
}
```

my problem actually in this part:

```
jar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor 
    from ('${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5') { 
        into 'static/apidocs'
    }
}
```

executed jar doesn't copy index.html file executed from asciidoctor into jar and jar executed only without this file

> So how i can copy **build/asciidoc/html5/index.html** from build
>   folder into executed jar?

Also if i need to use bootJar task so how i can make it include all jar needed into **/BOOT-INF/lib/**

Comment: It sounds like you need to customise the `bootJar` task rather than the `jar` task.

Comment: Ok, could u help on that? so it will be like jar task but must includes lib for external jars and html for rest docs too @AndyWilkinson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is almost right, but you are customising the wrong task. A Spring Boot fat jar is built with the `bootJar` task rather than the `jar` task.
You need to replace `jar` with `bootJar` in your `build.gradle`. This will result in it looking the same as the following example:

```
bootJar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor 
    from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") { 
        into 'static/docs'
    }
}
```

This is the configuration that's [described in the REST Docs documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration-packaging-the-documentation).